# Fieldname#- defining struct in racket

Tags: racket

Assuming that we have the following code in racket:

```
(struct st ( field1 field2# ))
```

What does the `#` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing, it's just part of the name `field2#`. Racket allows almost all symbols to be used in names. That's why you've got things like `hash-ref!` and `number?` that are ordinary functions, despite having unusual symbols.

You can access and set it like any other field:

```
(struct st (field1 field2#))
(define a (st 1 2))
(st-field1 a)
(st-field2# a)
```

This prints out

```
1
2
```

in the DrRacket REPL, just as you would expect of ordinary struct fields.

Comment: The tiny exception is you can't name an identifier with `#` as the _first_ character. That's reserved for reader macros. So for example `#foobar` isn't OK, but `f#oobar` is fine.

Comment: With a tiny exception to the tiny exception for the case where `#` is the first character and the _second_ character is `%`. `#%foobar` is a legal identifier. Racket identifier syntax is so incredibly permissive. Makes for a lovely fluency in code, using `?` for predicates is something I miss dearly whenever I use other languages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. If you have seen the notation field# in a text such as blog/book, then it might mean "field number". It is common to use # as an abbreviation of number.

If on the other hand you have seen it in code as in:

```
 (struct foo (bar#))
```

Then bar# simply the name of a field. As Jack writes, # is a legal character in names.